# Lambda Expression return type issue

Tags: c#, lambda

Why do the first and third expressions work but not the second?

```
        var ss = new Func<int>(() => 0); //works
        int x1 = new Func<int>(() => 0); //doesn't work --﻿Cannot convert source type 'System.Func<int>' to target type 'int'
        int x2 = new Func<string,int>((x) => 0)(""); //works
```

Comment: You're basically trying to put a `Func<int>` in a variable typed as `int` ; there is something wrong ;)

Comment: `int x1 = new Func<int>(() => 0)();` would work, as you then invoke the function expression, get the 0 result, and then assign that to the int. This doesn't really as much to do with return values though, and to note, the first works because you can assign anything to var. The third works because, again, you invoke the function expression (notably with a string as it expects).

Comment: @TravisJ we can't put anything in `var` ; "only" things whose type can be (statically ?) resolved from the expression. for example `var foo = delegate () { return 0; };` won't work

Comment: It was meant as an exaggeration. Sometimes intent is hard to convey with text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With

```
var ss = new Func<int>(() => 0);
```

the compiler is able to correctly infer the actual type of `ss` to be `Func<int>`. `Func<int>` is a delegate that can be invoked and returns an `int`. So:

```
ss() == 0 // is true
```

Notice that we had to invoke `ss` here (e.g. `ss()` ) in order for it to **return** an `int`.

So knowing what we do from above, the following can't be right

```
int x1 = new Func<int>(() => 0);
```

because you're now trying to store a function/delegate (identical to the previous one) into a variable typed as `int`. It's a delegate of type `Func<int>`... very different from an `int`, it's something that **returns** an `int` when called/invoked.

In this case

```
int x2 = new Func<string,int>((x) => 0)("");
```

you are declaring a function that takes a string as a parameter and returns an `int`, then immediately invoking it (supplying an unused empty string, `""` as the parameter). The function then returns the `int` which you then store against `x2`.

Makes more sense now?

Comment: Yes! It's the invocation part that I was not understanding. So, then, the cleanest method would be:  int x1 = new Func<int>(() => 0)(); There are two parts to the assignment -- the lambda expression and then invoking it which is what actually executes the func.and returns what I need returned.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the return type for your Func, like so,

```
int x1 = new Func<int, int>(() =<0);
```

You will notice, this also returns the same error.

`var` works because the value of `var` does not matter for type. C# is strongly typed so for `int`, the `Func` is expecting a value type of `int`.